# Deploy from Visual Studio Team Services to on-prem IIS - VPN connect

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Recently we start using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) online, as a source control and DevOps continuous integration. and we started to make builds. (VisualStudio.com)

We need the remote build to be able to deploy packages (IIS sites) to our on-premises servers (internal network servers like UAT , QA servers).

I'm not sure how to connect the VSTS to our network, are there a way to setup a VPN or something like that. I couldn't found in setting or documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of machines seems relative to the location of the build/deploy agent.

We just started playing with this, but here's what we have done so far:

- Set up build/deploy agents on our network (Azure vnet and local dev machine for our test). Instructions here:   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows
- Disable the Hosted build agent. (I'm sure there are better ways to do this)

At this point, the build/deploy is within your network, so the machines are listed as if you are accessing them locally from the agent. (127.0.0.1 is the agent etc)

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it worked with me. but no need to Disable the Hosted build agent, we can set the new agent as default agent for builds.

Comment: I set my home server up as a build agent about a year ago mainly because I ran out of hosted build time on VSTS and didn't want to pay for more.  I use this technique for our clients that have on prem installations so that we get the full CI / CD component.  I really think VSTS / Azure Dev ops now needs to develop a small agent that can be installed on machines for deploy (just like Octopus Deploy does).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Deployment Groups (need to contact Microsoft to enable on your account).  Then you can use the Hosted Agent and deploy locally into your network.  When you setup the Deployment Groups it creates a service that runs on the local machines that need to be deployed to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy to a local machine by creating a Deployment Group(did not had to contact Microsoft), and registering the machine via a PowerShell script that included the PAK, this was done by following the steps on the IIS Website Deployment template on create new release. I have the code hosted on VSTS, a Build definition for building online, and deploying in Azure and on a local machine. Hope it  helps.