# TFS Deploy Agent

Tags: tfs

I was trying to deploy my site using TFS release definition. For hosting the the site I am using MSDeploy Package Sync. Everything is fine but my hosted machine was in VPN so its showing below error while deploying throw TFS:

### [error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: More Information:  Could not connect to the remote computer ("developeriis"). Make sure that the remote computer name is correct and that you are able to connect to that computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINAT .

Same was working from my local machine which was connected to VPN. My question where should I add VPN details in TFS release definition?

Comment: A computer where installed the agent, is this computer in vpn?

Comment: I am using online TFS i.e https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/

Comment: and I am using Hosted agent

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to add the vpn details in TFS release definition. Seems you need to add the Hosted Agent machine to your VPN, obviously it's not available.

As a workaround you can try to [deploy your own private agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) that locates on your local machine or any other VMs within your VPN.

Then try to use the **Private Agent** for the deployment.

You can reference this thread:
[Deploy from Visual Studio Team Services to on-prem IIS - VPN connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720920/deploy-from-visual-studio-team-services-to-on-prem-iis-vpn-connect)